# Ruby 2.1.5p273 Time comparison with memory growth / leak?

Tags: ruby, memory-management, time

I spent a week to figure out why a one of my ruby script was growing in memory. I found the culprit line but i can't figure out why it grows in memory in one case and not in the other :

I have a simple eternal loop with a condition on a Time object :

```
i        = 0
lastTry = Time.now()

until i == 5    
  if (lastTry + 0.75) <  Time.now
    puts '.'
    lastTry = Time.now()
  end    
end
```

This will produce a process that will eat memory until my ram is full and eventually my kernel will stop allowing me forks or will panic at some point. Bad for my client.

If i replace my if with this :

```
if ((Time.now() - lastTry) * 1000.0) > 750.0
```

It won't eat memory anymore.

-> as stated in the comment, i could confirm that the origin of this is related to the outdated version of ruby used on my customer environment.

Comment: Are you aware that you are using a version of Ruby that is five years old and that there are several patches available for that version? The latest 2.1.10 was released more than three years ago. But even then, keep in mind that the support for that old Ruby 2.1 has ended [two and a half years ago](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2017/04/01/support-of-ruby-2-1-has-ended/). I suggest running the test against the current versions of Ruby.

Comment: I'll test it on a fresh ruby. Sometimes, on customer environnement, you don't have the choice of the ruby version you can use which is currently the case. Also, i fixed the puts '.'

Comment: Ok, on ruby 1.9.3, no memory problem. on ruby 2.6.5 no problem. With ruby 2.1.5 on arm or i386 platform -> memory problem. So that's a ruby 2.1.5 problem, not a code problem. Good to know.